# Verify mocked method call with lambda?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Using Mockito, I'd like to verify a mocked method call (particularly the parameters passed to it) via a lambda, without having to use a `Captor`, etc.

**MyThing**

```java
class MyThing {
  public void run() {
    // ... do stuff
    doSomething(someInt, someString);
  }

  public void doSomething(MyOtherThing otherThing) {
    // ... do more stuff
  }
}
```

**MyThingTests**

```java
@Test
public void ensure_doSomething_does_something() {
  MyThing thing = mock(MyThing.class);

  doCallRealMethod().when(thing).run();
  thing.run();

  thing.doSomething(any(), any()).verify(otherThing -> {
    assertEquals(1, otherThing.getCount());
    assertEquals("abc", otherThing.getName());
  });
}
```

The above test is intercepting the call to `doSomething` and verifying the parameter that was passed in. Note that this needs to work for methods which have a `void` return.

I could probably use `doAnswer` but it seems like a hack, not what it's intended for.

Comment: No need for any lambda: `verify(thing).doSomething(1, "abc")`. https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.27.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1

Comment: Sorry, will update the question, but the arguments are not value types, but instances of some class. I need to verify properties on the args passed.

Comment: Than use an argThat matcher: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.27.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers.

Comment: `argThat` works. Post an answer and I'll accept it.